# Turning MYSQL query backwards to get different return

Tags: mysql, database

Here's my tables from my database

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_db       |
+--------------------+
| it_survey          |
| lvis_survey        |
| schools            |
| subjects           |
| supplies_survey    |
| users              |
+--------------------+
```

And here's my query for getting total count of surveys posted based on user's id number for each of these three tables:

```
select count(user_id) AS posted_surveys from
(select user_id from it_survey where user_id = 7 UNION ALL
select user_id from lvis_survey where user_id = 7 UNION ALL
select user_id from supplies_survey where user_id = 7) tables;
```

The query above will return the value in the following way:

```
+--------------------+
| posted_surveys     |
+--------------------+
|                  2 |
+--------------------+
```

Now what I would like to achieve is basically turn this query upside down and get the value of unposted surveys based on
the amount of survey tables. I'm thinking I have to subtract the amount of tables from the posted_surveys count but don't know how to implement this.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Your main problem is the query itself. Running this query on a large set of data will take long to execute. Avoid using UNION ALL and subqueries when you can just do `joins` and `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1)`

Comment: Where is the `WHERE` keyword in all your subqueries?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted them when I copied this to notepad before posting this in here.

Comment: The parameter to EXISTS must be a subquery. That should also be WHERE.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I've tried every types of ways and accidentally copied the query from my notepad which was syntaxically wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IF` with `EXISTS` and subqueries:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM it_survey WHERE user_id = 7), 0, 1)
     + IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM lvis_survey WHERE user_id = 7), 0, 1)
     + IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM supplies_survey WHERE user_id = 7), 0, 1) AS unposted_surveys
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71f1c/6)

Reverse the order of the `0, 1` arguments to get the count of posted surveys.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't allow adding them. I had to wrap them in `IF`.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. It is working as it should now :) Cheers!